# Change default value initialization of scoped enum in C++ 20?

Tags: c++, enums, default-value

Is it possible to change the behavior of default value initialization of a scoped enum in C++ 20 ?

For exemple, in the following code, I'd like that a `MyEnum` variable to be initialized automaticatly with `MyEnum::No` when declared with `MyEnum myValue{};`

```
using MyEnumRootType = unsigned int;
using MyEnum = enum class EMyEnum: MyEnumRootType {
  Yes = 0x1,
  No = 0x2
};


int main() {
  const MyEnum myValue{}; // <- 0
  std::cout << static_cast<MyEnumRootType>(myValue);
}
```

edit:
I'v tried to write a wrapper like Benjamin Buch suggested (thanks).
I'm using template because I want it to be reusable.
I managed to handle a default value but I'm struggling to make it act like a real scoped enum (last line of main doesn't compile).

```
#include <concepts>

using MyEnumRootType = unsigned int;
enum class EMyEnum: MyEnumRootType {
  Yes = 0x1,
  No = 0x2
};

template<typename T>
concept ScopedEnum = std::is_enum_v<T> && !std::is_convertible_v<T, int>;

template<typename Enum, auto DefaultValue>
  requires ScopedEnum<Enum>
class EnumWrapper{
public:
  EnumWrapper(): value_(DefaultValue) {}
  EnumWrapper& operator=(Enum e) { value_ = e; return *this; }
  operator Enum() const { return value_; }
private:
  Enum value_;
};

using MyEnum = EnumWrapper<EMyEnum, EMyEnum::No>;

int main() {
  MyEnum a{};
  MyEnum b = MyEnum::Yes; // how can I make this works ?
}
```

Can I do something like this in a template https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Using-enum-declaration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible directly for an enumeration (except if you are willing to change the value of `No` to `0x0`). Enumerations are not class types (even if there is `class` in `enum class`), so you can't affect their behavior like you can with member functions/constructors/destructors/etc of classes.

Instead you'll have to make a class wrapper around it in which you can define a default constructor to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible to write a wrapper class to achieve this behavior. Use `using enum` to address the values of your enumeration directly via the wapper class. Define a data member of the enumeration type and a cast operator for this type.

```cpp
using MyEnumRootType = unsigned int;
enum class EMyEnum: MyEnumRootType {
  Yes = 0x1,
  No = 0x2
};

struct MyEnum {
    using enum EMyEnum;

    constexpr operator EMyEnum() const noexcept {
        return value;
    }

    EMyEnum value = No;
};

int main() {
    constexpr MyEnum myValue{};
    static_assert(myValue != MyEnum::Yes);
    static_assert(myValue == MyEnum::No);
    static_assert(myValue != EMyEnum{});
}
```